# How to execute Google Cloud Functions from Firebase Hosting?

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I'm trying to create an Android project which can send notifications from one android device to another. For that purpose, I created a node.js file, it's working fine on the local server. But when I hosted it on Google Cloud Platform, it shows Page Not Found. It is not able to call Google Function from hosting. It is looking for or executing index.html but it should execute index.js, which is in functions directory which was created while initializing the project with Firebase.

I took the reference from this video: https://youtu.be/pnysHgQvOiM?list=PLk7v1Z2rk4hjM2NPKqtWQ_ndCuoqUj5Hh

**index.js file**

```
  const functions = require('firebase-functions');

   var {google}  = require('googleapis')

 var MESSAGING_SCOPE ="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging"

  var SCOPES = [MESSAGING_SCOPE]

  var express = require('express')
  var app = express();
  var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
  var router = express.Router();
  var request = require('request');
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
  app.use(bodyParser.json());
  router.post('/send',function(req,res){

    getAccessToken().then(function(access_token){

    var title = req.body.title;
    var body = req.body.body;
    var token = req.body.token;

    request.post({ 
        headers:{
            Authorization: 'Bearer '+ access_token 
        }, url: 
  "https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/my_project_name/messages:send",
        body: JSON.stringify(


            {
                "message":{
                  "token" : token,
                  "notification" : {
                    "body" : body,
                    "title" : title
                    }
                 }
              }
        )

    },function(error,reponse,body){

        res.end(body);
        console.log(body);
           });
     });

   });

      app.use('/api',router);



       function getAccessToken()
{
     return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){

var key= require("./service-account.json");
var jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(


    key.client_email,
    null,
    key.private_key,
    SCOPES,
    null
);

jwtClient.authorize(function(error,tokens){

    if(error)
    {
        reject(error)
    }
    resolve(tokens.access_token)
  // console.log(tokens.access_token)
});

   jwtClient.authorize(function(error,tokens){

    if(error)
    {
        reject(error)
    }
    resolve(tokens.access_token)
    console.log(tokens.access_token)
  });

  });

 }
    exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

**firebase.json**

```
    { 
        "hosting": 
           {

"public": "public",


"rewrites": [
    {
      "source": "/api/send",
      "functions": "api"
    }
  ],
   "ignore": [
    "firebase.json",
    "**/.*",
    "**/node_modules/**"
 ]

               }

            }
```

This code is working fine with using http://localhost:8085/api/send but it is not working as https://my_project_name.firebaseapp.com/api/send

Comment: `https://my_project_name/api/send.firebaseapp.com` is not a valid hosting URL. Did you mean to use `https://my_project_name.firebaseapp.com/api/send`?

Comment: Oh! Please ignore that. I'm already using what you've suggested still I'm getting same result

Comment: Instead of telling us to ignore parts of the code in your question, edit your question to include the [minimal, correct code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I just did. Please help me to run index.js. Please tell me where can I make changes.

Comment: I don't immediately see what's wrong in the code/json you shared. Hopefully somebody else spots it.